# p:dataTable inside of ui:tab iteration component only does update model phase on the input fields in the last rendered tab

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

I am using a p:dataTable inside of a p:tab and p:tabView. Only the input fields in the last tab rendered (tab2) are getting processed and having the UPDATE MODEL JSF phase being applied to them. Is there something I am doing wrong and/or is there a workaround? I can provide a very small code snippet showing the issue:

XHTML:

```
<h:form> 
              <p:tabView value="#{TabTestBean.keySet.toArray()}" var="key">

                <p:tab title="#{key}" disabled="false">

                    <p:dataTable value="#{TabTestBean.testData[key]}" id="tabTestGrid" var="item">
                        <p:column headerText="Name">
                            <h:outputText value="#{item.name}" />
                        </p:column>

                        <p:column  headerText="Value">
                            <h:inputText value="#{item.value}" />
                        </p:column>
                </p:dataTable>
            </p:tab>
        </p:tabView>

        <p:commandButton process="@form" action="#{TabTestBean.save}"  value="Save" />
    </h:form>
```

Bean:

```
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.LinkedHashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Set;

import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.ViewScoped;
import javax.faces.context.FacesContext;

@ViewScoped
@ManagedBean(name="TabTestBean")
public class TabTestBean implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -3528195196098148161L;

    public static class TabTestModel {
        private String name;
        private String value;

        public TabTestModel(String name, String value) {
            this.name = name;
            this.value = value;
        }

        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }
        public void setName(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }
        public String getValue() {
            return value;
        }
        public void setValue(String value) {
            System.out.println("setting value = " + value + " is phase " + FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getCurrentPhaseId());
            this.value = value;
        }
    }

    private Map<String, List<TabTestModel>> testData = new LinkedHashMap<>();

    @PostConstruct
    public void loadTestData() {
        String key1 = "tab1";
        List<TabTestModel> list1 = new ArrayList<TabTestModel>();
        list1.add(new TabTestModel(key1, ""));
        list1.add(new TabTestModel(key1, ""));
        testData.put(key1, list1);

        String key2 = "tab2";
        List<TabTestModel> list2 = new ArrayList<TabTestModel>();
        list2.add(new TabTestModel(key2, ""));
        list2.add(new TabTestModel(key2, ""));
        testData.put(key2, list2);
    }

    public Set<String> getKeySet() {
        return testData.keySet();
    }

    public Map<String, List<TabTestModel>> getTestData() {
        return testData;
    }

    public void save() {
        for(List<TabTestModel> list: testData.values()) {
            for(TabTestModel t: list) {
                System.out.println(t.getName() + " = " + t.getValue());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Upon clicking entering values in the input fields (ie 1,2,3,4,) and clicking save, the following is the output:

```
13:32:50,613 INFO  [stdout] (http--0.0.0.0-8081-9) setting value = 3 is phase UPDATE_MODEL_VALUES 4 13:32:50,613 INFO  
[stdout] (http--0.0.0.0-8081-9) setting value = 4 is phase UPDATE_MODEL_VALUES
4 13:32:50,613 INFO  [stdout] (http--0.0.0.0-8081-9) tab1 = 
13:32:50,613 INFO  [stdout] (http--0.0.0.0-8081-9) tab1 = 
13:32:50,613 INFO  [stdout] (http--0.0.0.0-8081-9) tab2 = 3
13:32:50,613 INFO  [stdout] (http--0.0.0.0-8081-9) tab2 = 4
```

The values that I entered in the input fields in the first tab are never processed. I would like to avoid having an ajax call on focus out of any input field in the row to update these values - I think the form submit should correctly handling this case.

Version info: Primefaces 5.2 with JSF 2.2 on Jboss 7.1.

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround, If I change my XHTML to the following, everything now works as expected. However, either I am misunderstanding of how something should work, or there is a bug in Primefaces. If I explicitly specify the tabs and don't have them as part of an iteration component, it produces the expecting results. This is fine if the values of tab1 and tab2 are known ahead of time, but if these values are **truly dynamic** then the below solution is not going to work. I am also going to try this with a c:forEach to add the tab components in there.

XHTML (updated):

```
<h:form>
            <p:tabView>

                <p:tab title="Tab 1" disabled="false">

                    <p:dataTable value="#{TabTestBean.testData['tab1']}" id="tabTestGrid1" var="item">
                        <p:column headerText="Name">
                            <h:outputText value="#{item.name}" />
                        </p:column>

                        <p:column  headerText="Value">
                            <h:inputText value="#{item.value}" />
                        </p:column>
                    </p:dataTable>
                </p:tab>

                    <p:tab title="Tab 2" disabled="false">

                    <p:dataTable value="#{TabTestBean.testData['tab2']}" id="tabTestGrid2" var="item">
                        <p:column headerText="Name">
                            <h:outputText value="#{item.name}" />
                        </p:column>

                        <p:column  headerText="Value">
                            <h:inputText value="#{item.value}" />
                        </p:column>
                    </p:dataTable>
                </p:tab>


        </p:tabView>

        <p:commandButton process="@form" action="#{TabTestBean.save}"  value="Save" />
    </h:form>
```

Comment: Check the issuelist in PF github. There is something (partially) when using iterating components.

Comment: I searched yesterday and didn't see something specific to the tabView component. Can you provide a direct link?

Comment: It is not specific to the tabview, it was reported against the datatable. But now I think of it, that was using it inva repeat, so most likely not applicable here

Comment: Otohx it is a datatable in a tab which is also a kind of repeat. Are you actually running 5.3 btw?

Comment: Otohx? What is the specific link and/or issue number? No, I am running 5.2, I put 5.3 by mistake. I will edit the question above.

Comment: Should have been otoh. No x. Issue is https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/issues/88 the solution pf made might solve more tgan the title suggests